# SQL query count rows with the same entry

Tags: sql

Given a dataset **Roster_table** as such:

| Group ID | Group Name | Name | Phone |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 42 | Red Dragon | Jon | 123455678 |
| 32 | Green Lizard | Liz | 932143211 |
| 19 | Blue Falcon | Ben | 134554678 |
| 42 | Red Dragon | Reed | 432143211 |
| 42 | Red Dragon | Brad | 231314155 |
| 19 | Blue Falcon | Chad | 214124412 |

How do I get the following query output combining rows with the same **Group ID** from the dataset, and the new column **Count** in descending order:

| Group ID | Group Name | Count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 42 | Red Dragon | 3 |
| 19 | Blue Falcon | 2 |
| 32 | Green Lizard | 1 |

`SELECT * FROM Roster_table`

Comment: You have tagged your request with both MySQL and PostgreSQL. I doubt you are using two different DBMS. Please only tag your request with the DBMS you are using. I've removed the contradicting tags. Please add the appropriate DBMS tag back.

Comment: You want to count values and you haven't been able to find SQL's `COUNT`? `SELECT * FROM Roster_table` is all you have come up with? Then maybe you should just read the next few pages in your SQL tutorial or book. Aggregation (counts, sums, ...) are rather basic.

Comment: Thank you for the input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this where alias tot_count is used in ORDER BY clause.

```
-- PostgreSQL(v11)
SELECT Group_ID
     , MAX(Group_Name) Group_Name
     , COUNT(1) tot_count
FROM Roster_table
GROUP BY Group_ID
ORDER BY tot_count DESC;
```

Please check from url https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=b66f9f0d40e804e89be12e3530fe00a0

Comment: Note that in Postgres `count(1)` is actually a bit _slower_ than `count(*)` in case you expected `count(1)` to magically make things faster (hint: it doesn't, there is no database where `count(1)` is faster than `count(*)`)

Comment: ```MAX(Group_Name) Group_Name```

Why is MAX used?

Comment: ```SELECT Group_ID, Group_Name, COUNT(*)
FROM Roster_table
GROUP BY Group_ID, Group_Name
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC```

Comment: It isn't necessary to use the MAX() function IF the data in the name column is consistent, if however it isn't consistent then using the MAX function would keep the result to one row per `group_id`. Nevertheless this answer has triggered your solution.

Comment: Max(group_name) is used to avid extra cost because id wise name is unique.

Answer (score 0):

Based on Rahul Biswas's answer:

[Solution without using Max function](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=02bf8ab65d0fb5756ea82098c197dd3e)

```
SELECT Group_ID, Group_Name, COUNT(*)
FROM Roster_table
GROUP BY Group_ID, Group_Name
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
```

Credit goes to Eric S.